# MySQL gem install error on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am using Windows 7 and creating connection to MySQL2. I need to install gem. I am following these steps. Could someone please review them:

1. Add the following to the Gemfile: `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.15'`
2. Run the following in `cmd`: `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.15'`
3. Go to the application using cmd and run this code: `bundle install`

When I perform step (3), I get the following error:

> An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.15), and bundler cannot
>   continue make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v "0.3.15" ' succeeds
>   before bundling..

My application resides on the D drive and I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution that works on Ubuntu.

My mistake was that had not installed the `my-sql` library before trying to connect.

Please follow these steps to do this. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

sudo gem install mysql2
```

Add the following to the gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.15'
```

And then run:

```
bundle install
```